# Getting doInBackground errors and can't seem to fix them

Tags: android, android-intent, background

I'm trying to fetch a string via Json ('naam') and display it in a textview. When I intent to the activity it crashes (sometimes after a second). I don't know what I'm doing wrong and I've looked at the other questions here, but the solutions didn't work (but thats probobly me..). Thanks in advance!

*public class Recept extends Activity {*

```
String receptid;
String result;

JSONParser jsonparser = new JSONParser();
TextView tv;
String ab;
JSONObject jobj = null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recept);

    receptid = getIntent().getStringExtra("receptid");

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.receptTitel);
    new retrievedata().execute();
    //new ReceptAsynTask().execute("http://janvandijk.me/zooi/receptenapp/getrecipes.php?type=request&datatype=recept&id=" + receptid);

}

class retrievedata extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        jobj = jsonparser.makeHttpRequest("http://janvandijk.me/zooi/receptenapp/getrecipes.php?type=request&datatype=recept&id=1" /*+ receptid*/);

        // check your log for json response
        //Log.d("Shit terug: ", jobj.toString());

        try {
            ab = jobj.getString("naam");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ab;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String ab){
        setText(ab);
    }

}

public void setText(String string){
    tv.setText(string);
}

public void showToast(){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bezig met laden recept met ID "+receptid, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_recept, menu);
    //TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testje);
    //view.setText(receptid);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

*}*

*public class JSONParser{*

```
static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jobj = null;
static String json = "";
public JSONParser(){

}
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url){
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
    try {
        HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity httpentity = httpresponse.getEntity();
        is = httpentity.getContent();

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"utf-8"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        try {
            while((line = reader.readLine())!=null){
                sb.append(line+"\n");

            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            try {
                jobj = new JSONObject(json);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return jobj;

}
```

*}*

*The Error:*

```
11-04 14:21:27.437    1356-1541/me.janvandijk.receptenapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
Process: me.janvandijk.receptenapp, PID: 1356
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.toString()' on a null object reference
        at me.janvandijk.receptenapp.Recept$retrievedata.doInBackground(Recept.java:62)
        at me.janvandijk.receptenapp.Recept$retrievedata.doInBackground(Recept.java:54)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            JSONArray ja = jsonparser.makeHttpRequest("http://janvandijk.me/zooi/receptenapp/getrecipes.php?type=request&datatype=recept&id=1" /*+ receptid*/);

            // check your log for json response
            //Log.d("Shit terug: ", jobj.toString());

            try {
                ab = ja[0].getString("naam");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return ab;
        }
```

I think it jsonArray.

and you should use volley to parse json. it very easy and fast

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObjlist.getJSONArray("#name of your array");
```

but before that you should name your array, without it you can't fetch the appropriate data

change your response as this:

```
{"#name of your array":[{"id":"2","naam":"Bastogneparfait a la Kim","beschrijving":"Gemaakt van Bastogne, het lekkerste gerecht ooit!","ingredienten":"Bastogne parfait ingredi\u00ebnten\r\n40 gram eierdooiers (gepasteuriseerd)\r\n45 gram hele eieren (gepasteuriseerd)\r\n100 gram suiker \r\n2,5 dl slagroom ongezoet\r\n4  bastognekoeken \r\nKaralmelsaus ingredi\u00ebnten\r\n100 gram suiker \r\n2 dl koksroom ","bereiding":"Slagroom opkloppen tot yoghurt dikte. De eidooiers, hele eieren en suiker in een bekken doen en au bain-marie verwarmen tot 37 graden Celsius. Koud kloppen in de keukenmachine tot een luchtige massa. Spatel de massa door de slagroom. Kruimel de bastognekoeken en spatel ze voorzichtig door de massa. Vul de vormpjes en zet in diepvries.\nBereidingswijze karamelsaus\nDoe de suiker in een pan en verwarm de suiker tot deze is gekaramelliseerd. Haal de pan van het vuur en voeg de koksroom toe. Laat de karamel goed oplossen in de koksroom regelmatig roeren. Als de massa glad is af laten koelen.\nOpdienen\nHaal de parfait uit de vorm en leg in een tapasschaaltje. Doe er karamelsaus bij en een toefje slagroom op de parfait. Eventueel af garneren met een takje mint.","auteur":"2","imgurl":"https:\/\/s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com\/236x\/ea\/ea\/02\/eaea02155df75a711045371a3c1d169e.jpg","timestamp":"2015-10-22 14:42:14","unaam":"Arjen van Gaal","email":"arjenvangaal@gmail.com","wachtwoord":"arjen","iban":"NL93 ABNA 0000 1234 56","telefoonnummer":"629466064","x":"0"}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a nullpointer exception on your JSON object meaning your task is likely fine but there is an issue in you json object creation

Answer (score 1):

> Caused by: **java.lang.NullPointerException**: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.toString()' **on a null object reference
>           at** me.janvandijk.receptenapp.Recept$retrievedata.doInBackground(**Recept.java:62**)

You are returning `ab` also if it is `null` inside your `doInBackground` function. But you want to return a `String` (look at the return value)

Try to return an empty String inside the catch-clause above that

```
try 
{
    ab = jobj.getString("naam");
} 
catch (JSONException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
    return "";
}
return ab;
```

So you won't return a `null`, which down the chain will be treated as String.